# App crashes in FroYo & Gingerbread

Tags: android

--The anonymous answer is my answer that I solved this issue with.--

I have been writing an app for Android, all is working well in Honeycomb, but not playing nice on my FroYo & Gingerbread devices (opposite of what you'd expect right).

Here is the code that I believe is causing the issue:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    int versionNumber = Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK);
    if (versionNumber == 11) {
        super.onStart();
        ActionBar actionBar = this.getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Here I implement the ActionBar's icon-up-to-home ability, I added the versionNumber variable as I believed the lack of an ActionBar in pre-Honyecomb devices was causing the issue when the activity was run, but it still crashes and I believe this is the issue, although I am terrible with debugging and don't understand anything I am given by logcat.

Edit: logcat - I hope I got the right section?!

> 08-20 17:21:41.326: WARN/ActivityManager(2707): Trying to launch
>   com.squirculardesign.android.pixel/.About 08-20 17:21:41.346:
>   INFO/dalvikvm(4059): Could not find method
>   com.squirculardesign.android.pixel.About.getActionBar, referenced from
>   method com.squirculardesign.android.pixel.About.onStart 08-20
>   17:21:41.346: WARN/dalvikvm(4059): VFY: unable to resolve virtual
>   method 54: Lcom/squirculardesign/android/pixel/About;.getActionBar
>   ()Landroid/app/ActionBar; 08-20 17:21:41.346: DEBUG/dalvikvm(4059):
>   VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0011 08-20 17:21:41.346:
>   DEBUG/dalvikvm(4059): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0018 in
>   Lcom/squirculardesign/android/pixel/About;.onStart ()V 08-20
>   17:21:41.386: INFO/ALSAModule(2588): Initialized ALSA PLAYBACK device
>   hifi 08-20 17:21:41.386: WARN/AudioFlinger(2588): write blocked for
>   108 msecs, 3 delayed writes, thread 0x5e758 08-20 17:21:41.406:
>   DEBUG/dalvikvm(4059): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 38K, 52% free
>   2621K/5379K, external 190K/518K, paused 36ms 08-20 17:21:41.596:
>   INFO/AudioFlinger(2588): stop output streamType (0, 1) for 1 08-20
>   17:21:41.596: DEBUG/AudioHardwareYamaha(2588):
>   AudioStreamOut::setParameters(keyValuePairs="stop_output_streamtype=1")
>   08-20 17:21:42.096: ERROR/yamaha::media::Parameters(2588): SalesCode =
>   OPS 08-20 17:21:42.671: ERROR/lights(2707): write_int: path
>   /sys/devices/virtual/misc/melfas_touchkey/brightness, value 2 08-20
>   17:21:42.671: WARN/PowerManagerService(2707): Timer 0x7->0x3|0x3 08-20
>   17:21:42.671: INFO/PowerManagerService(2707): Ulight 7->3|0 08-20
>   17:21:42.671: DEBUG/PowerManagerService(2707): setLightBrightness :
>   mButtonLight : 0 08-20 17:21:43.666: INFO/ALSAModule(2588): Terminated
>   ALSA PLAYBACK device hifi 08-20 17:21:44.086:
>   ERROR/yamaha::media::Parameters(2588): SalesCode = OPS 08-20
>   17:21:51.181: WARN/ActivityManager(2707): Launch timeout has expired,
>   giving up wake lock! 08-20 17:21:51.336: WARN/ActivityManager(2707):
>   Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{40a6f0a8
>   com.squirculardesign.android.pixel/.About} 08-20 17:21:56.456:
>   DEBUG/dalvikvm(2929): GC_EXPLICIT freed 672K, 53% free 3917K/8327K,
>   external 12588K/12670K, paused 121ms 08-20 17:22:01.876:
>   INFO/StatusBarPolicy(2834): onSignalStrengthsChanged 08-20
>   17:22:04.006: DEBUG/BatteryService(2707): update start 08-20
>   17:22:04.011: ERROR/BatteryService(2707): TMU status = 0 08-20
>   17:22:04.011: DEBUG/BatteryService(2707): updateBattery level:79
>   scale:100 status:2 health:2 present:true voltage: 4050 temperature:
>   270 technology: Li-ion AC powered:false USB powered:true icon:17302229

Comment: Can you post the error from logcat?

Comment: Added, I hope I copied the correct section?? Also; the formatting sucks sorry.

Comment: Just saying, it's a bad idea to test for an exact SDK version number. At least you should do >= to be compatible with future versions (when you can't check for a particular feature).

Comment: I did initially have it as >=, and I always intended to have it as >= before any kind of release, but after I looked at it logically and couldn't work out my error, I started tinkering with things that could possibly have tripped it up.

Comment: The anonymous answer is my answer that I solved this issue with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This always seems to happen, I ask the question and the problem becomes clearer in my mind after having explained it so someone not in the context could understand...

The fix I found was:

```
//Sets the icon to 'go home' button
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    int versionNumber = Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK);
    if (versionNumber >= 11) {
            super.onStart();
            ActionBar actionBar = this.getActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    else {
            super.onStart();
    }
}
```

This fixes the problem in both Gingerbread & FroYo, the difference is that super.onStart(); us triggered no matter what.

For those of you who are inevitably going to comment on my hackish/sticky tape fix: This particular App does not need an ActionBar always, I was just using the ActionBar items in Honeycomb as it has become the UI practice to get more actions. This is why I did not implement an Ac

Comment: This is my answer that I found, but has to post anonymously as I can't post answers to my own question for 8 hours until my rep > 100, so kindly +1 my question so I can :P.

Comment: Why not super.onStart() first, then do the action bar lines in the if and bin the else?

Answer (score 3):

Have you logged what versionNumber actually is? I guess your if statement somehow is true. So try logging what versionNumber equals.

You should really use

```
int versionNumber = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
```

Answer (score 0):

Check also this:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourHomeActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

You have to declare "item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home" and ten "give" the name of your Home Activity "YourHomeActivity.class".
Now when someone press the "up" button you wll be redirected to your Home activity "YourHomeActivity.class".